# wait for previous stream to be empty before allowing reading

Tags: node.js, stream, duplex

Say I have a file that contains a list of integers, one per line. I use `fs.createReadStream` and pipe that into `split` (so that each chunk is an integer). Then I pipe that into a duplex stream that is supposed to add the numbers and write the sum by piping into `fs.createWriteStream`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = require('stream');
var split = require('split');

var addIntegers = new stream.Duplex();

addIntegers.sum = 0;

addIntegers._read = function(size) {
  this.push(this.sum + '\n');
}

addIntegers._write = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  this.sum += +chunk;
  done();
}

fs.createReadStream('list-of-integers.txt')
  .pipe(split())
  .pipe(addIntegers)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('sum.txt'));
```

When I run this, `sum.txt` just gets continually filled with zeroes and the program never terminates (as expected). How do I wait for the input stream (`split`) to be empty before allowing the ouput stream (`fs.createWriteStream`) to read from `addIntegers`?

Comment: Why not `push()` inside `_write()` instead?

Comment: Hmm yes I could use a transform stream and `this.push(this.sum + '\n')` in `_write`. I get a running total this way which is much better than zeroes forever. However, is there any way to just get the overall total? (write once to `sum.txt` instead of n times?). I realize I can just `tail -n 1 sum.txt` afterwards, but I was wondering if there's an idiomatic `node` way to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I decided to use a [Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) stream instead (thanks mscdex) because it has a method ([`_flush`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_flush_callback)) that gets called after all written data is consumed. The working code is below. Don't forget to `npm i split` :)

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = require('stream');
var split = require('split');

var addIntegers = new stream.Transform();

addIntegers.sum = 0;

addIntegers._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  this.sum += +chunk;
  done();
}

addIntegers._flush = function(done) {
  this.push(this.sum + '\n');
}

fs.createReadStream('list-of-integers.txt')
  .pipe(split())
  .pipe(addIntegers)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('sum.txt'));
```